# sqflite failed to read the directory in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, sqflite

the error appears without any changes that I do:

```
> * What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.                 
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Path '/Users/mac/Documents/projects/build/sqflite/intermediates/compiled_local_resources/debug/out' is not a readable directory.
```

Comment: Can you share the app/build.gradle file?

Comment: thank you for the response, take a look here https://pastebin.com/nn87FXnm

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by upgrading Gradle and kotlin

[image: gradle upgrade]

[image: kotlin upgrade]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following line into your `app/build.gradle` file.

```
 buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
```

Look at the [official document](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools) for more info.

Comment: I think this is a problem in its sqflite

Comment: it turned out to be a gradle problem that needed updating, and I got it now done